# How to parse and store parts of a JSON object using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a JSON data and I want to parse it. The user has some checkbox and with the checked one I want to parse the JSON to only returns the parts that the user is asking for.

```js
if (document.getElementById('jsonData').checked) {
  if (document.getElementById('fullbody').checked) {
    toast.success('We will download a JSON file ' + document.getElementById('jsonData').checked);
    download("data.json", true, JSON.stringify(this.state.jsondata));
  } else {
    let myParsedJson
    if (document.getElementById('upperbody').checked) {
      // here I want to parse this.state.jsondata to get only the part called upperbody
    }
    if (document.getElementById('lowerbody').checked) {
      // here I want to parse this.state.jsondata to get only the part called lowerbody
    }
    if (document.getElementById('head').checked) {
      // here I want to parse this.state.jsondata to get only the part called head
    }
    if (document.getElementById('lefthand').checked) {
      // here I want to parse this.state.jsondata to get only the part called lefthand
    }
    if (document.getElementById('righthand').checked) {
      // here I want to parse this.state.jsondata to get only the part called righthand
    }
    download("data.json", true, JSON.stringify(myParsedJson));
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="fullbody" />
  <label htmlFor="fullbody">Download the points for the full body</label>
  <ul id="ul_o">
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="upperbody" />Download only the upper body points</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="lowerbody" />Download only the lower body points</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="head" />Download only the head points</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="lefthand" />Download left hand points</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="righthand" />Download right hand points</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

As you can see in the snippet, I want to add the part I need to a new Json object but I can't figure out how to do it, I wish I could just do `myParsedJson += this.state.jsondata.xyz` in every if but it doesn't seem to work.

[edit]
The JSON data looks like this :

```
{
   "path":"064ff328-9e6b-47d5-9ead-00d776daffe4.jpg",
   "path_only_skeleton":"ffde8f31-99aa-41c6-9613-a3f62053ded0.jpg",
   "data":{
      "upperbody":[
         [
            [
               1100.424072265625,
               183.25262451171875,
               0.7656620740890503
            ]
      ],
      "lowerbody":[
         [
            [
               [
                  1287.9613037109375,
                  276.342529296875,
                  0.002401081845164299
               ]
            ]
         ]
      ],  
      "head":[
         [
            [
               [
                  1287.9613037109375,
                  276.342529296875,
                  0.002401081845164299
               ]
            ]
         ]
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: JSON is a string format - JavaScript OBJECT Notation and not an object. Please show example of the expected object

Comment: It looks like you do not want to PARSE it but to set member of the object before you download the stringified object

Comment: yes I want to take only some part of it before downloading the stringified object

Comment: So what is "only the upper body" You need to show an example object and expected output

Comment: @mplungjan I added a preview of the data

Comment: Loop over the checked checkboxes and include the data[checkbox.id]

Comment: The loop isn't that much necessary I can do it with my 5 if, but how can I add parts to the `myParsedJson` ?

Comment: I updated my snippet since checkedData is not an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

I had to add some ]] into the first item

```js
const data = { "path": "064ff328-9e6b-47d5-9ead-00d776daffe4.jpg", "path_only_skeleton": "ffde8f31-99aa-41c6-9613-a3f62053ded0.jpg", 
"data": { 
"upperbody": [ [ [ [ 1100.424072265625, 183.25262451171875, 0.7656620740890503 ] ] ] ], 
"lowerbody": [ [ [ [ 1287.9613037109375, 276.342529296875, 0.002401081845164299 ] ] ] ], 
"head": [ [ [ [ 1287.9613037109375, 276.342529296875, 0.002401081845164299 ] ] ] ] } };

if (document.getElementById('jsonData').checked) {
  if (document.getElementById('fullbody').checked) {
    //  toast.success('We will download a JSON file ' + document.getElementById('jsonData').checked);
    //  download("data.json", true, JSON.stringify(this.state.jsondata));
  } else {
    const checkedData = {}
    Object.keys(data.data).forEach(key => {
      console.log(key, document.getElementById(key).checked);
      if (document.getElementById(key).checked) checkedData[key] = data.data[key]
    });

    let myParsedJson = {
      path: data.path,
      path_only_skeleton: data.path_only_skeleton,
    }
    if (Object.keys(checkedData).length) myParsedJson.data = checkedData;


    // download("data.json", true, JSON.stringify(myParsedJson));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(myParsedJson))
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="jsonData" checked /> <input type="checkbox" id="fullbody" />
  <label htmlFor="fullbody">Download the points for the full body</label>
  <ul id="ul_o">
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="upperbody" checked/>Download only the upper body points</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="lowerbody" checked />Download only the lower body points</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="head" />Download only the head points</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="lefthand" />Download left hand points</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="righthand" />Download right hand points</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myParsedJson['upperbody'] = this.state.jsondata.upperbody
```

or

```
myParsedJson = { ...myParsedJson, upperbody: this.state.jsondata.upperbody }`
```

Comment: yes but then at the next line when I want to add maybe, left hand how can I do that ?

Comment: You do the same but with `lefthand` instead of `upperbody` :)